# Knowing in what part the method returned

Tags: c#, database, interceptor

Is it possible to get run-time information about where a method has returned?

I mean, if the method returned after running all its lines of code, or because of an earlier 
return statement that occurred due to some condition.

The scenario is using interceptor for creating UnitOfWork that should exists in method scope.
For example, lets consider this code:

```
[UnitOfWork]
public void Foo()
{
    // insert some values to the database, using repositories interfaces...
    DoSomeChangesInTheDataBaseUsingRepositories();
    var result = DoSomethingElse();
    if (!result) return;

    DoMoreLogicBecuseTheResultWasTrue();            
}
```

I have interceptor class that opens thread static unit of work for methods that are flagged with [UnitOfWork] and when the scope of the method ends it run commit on the UoW and dispose it.

This is fine, but lets consider the scenario above, where for some reason a programmer decided to return in the middle of the method due to some condition, and in that scenario the changes made by the repositories should not be persisted.

I know that this can indicate wrong design of the method, but be aware that it is a possible scenario to be written by a programmer and I want to defend my database from these kind of scenarios.

Also, I don't want to add code to the method itself that will tell me where it ended. I want to infer by the method info somehow its returned point, and if it is not at the end of its scope the interceptor will know not to commit.

Comment: What is your scenario and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not without its cooperation/re-writing.

Comment: create a somekind of log

Comment: You could look into profiling as well, although it's difficult to recommend anything since you don't describe what you want to accomplish.

Comment: If the code calling `Foo()` _needs to know about the result of `DoSomethingElse()`_, you should probably return it in some kind of way. Consider creating a FooResult class or struct that encapsulates all the information your method needs to expose to the caller. Refrain from just changing the `void` to `bool`; your method doesn't just `DoSomeThingElse()`, it does `SomeChanges...` and `MoreLogic...` as well (which wouldn't be obvious from reading the calling code).

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is use `BREAKPOINTS` and Debugging.

**Edit:-** *As mentioned by Mels in the comments. This could be a useful suggestion.*

*If your application is very timing-sensitive, set conditional breakpoints such that they never actually stop the flow of execution. They do keep track of Hit Count, which you can use to backtrace the flow of execution.*

Just for your attention. From the microsoft site:-

> For those out there who have experience debugging native C++ or VB6
>   code, you may have used a feature where function return values are
>   provided for you in the Autos window. Unfortunately, this
>   functionality does not exist for managed code. While you can work
>   around this issue by assigning the return values to a local variable,
>   this is not as convenient because it requires modifying your code. In
>   managed code, it’s a lot trickier to determine what the return value
>   of a function you’ve stepped over. We realized that we couldn’t do the
>   right thing consistently here and so we removed the feature rather
>   than give you incorrect results in the debugger. However, we want to
>   bring this back for you and our CLR and Debugger teams are looking at
>   a number potential solutions to this problem. Unfortunately this is
>   will not be part of Visual Studio 11.

Comment: It will be in VS 2013. It's the main new feature :-)

Comment: Might be a useful addition: If your application is very timing-sensitive, set conditional breakpoints such that they never actually stop the flow of execution. They _do_ keep track of Hit Count, which you can use to backtrace the flow of execution.

Comment: OP has edited the question, it's now apparent that debugging isn't going to solve his problem. He needed the information for actual flow control (which reeks of bad design) - I made some suggestions in a comment...

Comment: @Mels:- That was really a nice suggestion. Updated my answer with you suggestion!! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways that normally indicate that a method exited early for some reason, one is to use the actual return value, if the value is a valid result that then your method probably finished correctly, if its another value then probably not, this is the pattern that most `TryXXX` methods follow

```
int i;
//returns false as wasn't able to complete
bool passed = int.TryParse("woo", out i);
```

the other is to catch/trhow an exception, if an exception is found, then the method did not complete as you'd expect

```
try
{
Method();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//Something went wrong (e.StackTrace)
}
```

Note: Catching `Exception` is a bad idea, the correct exceptions should be caught, i.e `NullReferenceException`

**EDIT:**

In answer to your update, if your code is dependant on the success of your method you should change the return type to a boolean or otherwise, return false if unsuccessful

Comment: it's also bad to use exceptions as normal program flow (i.e. "don't save because I threw an exception"). Not saying you should remove it, just for those reading and thinking of using it.

Comment: I agree, Default. I have it in answer as I have read (original) question as how to tell when a method didn't complete correctly

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should use trace logs to watch you code flow if you cant debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like this:

```
private Tuple<int, MyClass> MyMethod()
{
    if (condition)
    {
        return new Tuple<int, MyClass>(0,new MyClass());
    }
    else if(condition)
    {
        return new Tuple<int, MyClass>(1, new MyClass());
    }

    return new Tuple<int, MyClass>(2,new MyClass());
}
```

This way you´ll have an index of which return was returning your MyClass object. All depends on what you are trying to accomplish and why - which is at best unclear. As someone else mentioned - that is what return values are for.

I am curios to know what you are trying to do...